# Periodic Gaussian Process's Covariance Matrix not Positive Definite

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'm trying to implement a periodic Gaussian Process:

```
GP = Table[Exp[-.1 Sin[\[Pi] (x - y)]^2], {x, 0., 3, .1}, {y, 0., 3, .1}];  
PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[GP]
```

> False

I'd like to be able to use this in the `RandomVariate` function, but can't because it is not positive definite.

Any help in pointing out anything I am doing wrong would be gratefully received.

Am using Mathematica 8.0.1.0, if that is relevant.

Comment: It looks like you may not have set up your matrix correctly. Look at GP//MatrixForm and verify that it has the values you expect.

Comment: GP = Table[
    Exp[-.1 Sin[\[Pi] (x - y)]^2], {x, 0., 3, .1}, {y, 0., 3, .1}] // 
   Rationalize[#, 0.000001] &;
GP // Det

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of numerical precision. Your matrix is symmetric, so it is positive definite if all eigenvalues are positive. Looking at the eigenvalues, however, shows that some of them are very close to zero. Check the **Possible Issues** section on `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[]`.  Then you need to define your table as `Table[...{0,3,1/10}]` and use `N[]` with according precision. I just checked it on *Alpha* with

```
Eigenvalues[Table[Exp[-1/10 Sin[x-y]^2],{x,0,2,.1},{x,0,2,.1}]]
```

vs

```
Eigenvalues[Table[Exp[-1/10 Sin[x-y]^2],{x,0,2,1/10},{x,0,2,1/10}]]
```

The first one giving the last 2 eigenvalues negative while the second one has all eigenvalues positive.

Comment: Thanks Mikuszefski, that change to symbolic calculation and then taking N seems to do the trick, ie all eigenvalues positive. Sadly, Mathematica still doesn't like the covariance matrix (for use in RandomVariate on Multinormal Distribution), this time it complains about the Cholesky decomposition. I suspect I need to think of a slightly different way of doing this, given the extreme numerical instability issues. (Would upvote, but don't have enough reputation to do so at the moment)

Comment: @JulianFrancis Surely you run into similar problems as the decoposition has similar requirements (*Matrices need to be positive definite enough to overcome numerical roundoff*). If this specific form of the matrix is not explicitly required, it is probably a good idea to choose one with somewhat bigger eigenvalues.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html  This link will help you  ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.I guess the link was meant for the OP?